# How is JavaScript and JQuery code moved from an MVC View to an external .js file for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am getting squiggly green underlines in JQuery code I have moved from my MVC View to an external .js file.  The code is fine in an MVC View but not in the external file. What needs to be done to the external .js file in my Visual Studio 2017 project so the code is recognized?  Below is a picture of JQuery code which Visual Studio 2017 is showing problems with in a .js file where I pasted code to from my MVC View:

[image]

Below is an example of one of the reported problems in Visual Studio 2017:

[image]

This code is fine in my MVC View with no such green underlines.  What is the problem with .js file I am using and how do I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using .js (external javascript file) then you dont have to define

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Your JS Code
</script>
```

So Just remove `<script>` tags.

Now your .js files looks like

**//Your JS Code**

Comment: Removing the <script> tags as suggested fixed the problem. Thanks.